# Combining absolute positions with centered text

Tags: html, css, position, center, element

I have a problem with positioning 3 separate text elements within a div.

Here's what I want to achieve

[image: White div is the 'ioitem']

Task, simplified:

1. The number in the center must be centered, no matter how wide it is. (auto-centered)
2. The number below must be on the left
3. The letter below must be on the right

My idea:

1. Create a parenting container for the number in the center
2. Place a block element to contain the number, which is also automatically centered as required
3. Do absolute positioning of other elements within `.ioitem`.

I used the following code

```
<div class="ioitem ioitem1">
    <div class="numberContainer">
        <div class="number">1</div>
        <div class="width">3</div>
        <div class="base">D</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Styles

```
.ioitem {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    height: 30px;

    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

    position: relative;
}
.ioitem1 {  width: 30px; }
.ioitem > .numberContainer {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.ioitem > .number {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

What I got is this mess:

[image]

The number to be in the center isnt centered and pretty much anything is not being placed as I would wish. I omitted some CSS for sake of brevity.

Please, how could I get the desired result? A list of steps would be enough.

The thing that causes me headache is making the `.number`´s text to be centered automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS table layout, since table cell has the `vertical-align` features. Note, I reordered the HTML tags slightly, put the number in the middle.

```css
body {
  background: silver;
}
.numberContainer {
  background: white;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.width, .number, .base {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
.width, .base {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.number {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="ioitem ioitem1">
  <div class="numberContainer">
    <div class="width">3</div>
    <div class="number">1</div>
    <div class="base">D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4tha983c/)**

Comment: I won't pretend I understand how this works, but it seems like the most elegant solution. If you were to describe in two sentences what you'd done, what would you say? Could each of the child divs now be considered a table cell with different vertical alignment?

Comment: I added some description in to this demo - https://jsfiddle.net/4tha983c/1/ that should explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this code. http://codepen.io/nehemc/pen/LkyJYN

```
<style>
.ioitem { display: inline-block; background: #C03; height: 200px; margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; position: relative; width:200px; color:#fff; }
.number { position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0; height:10px; margin:auto; text-align:center; }
.width { position:absolute; left:20px; bottom:20px; height:10px; margin:auto; text-align:center; background:#fff; padding:10px; color:#000; }
.base { position:absolute; right:20px; bottom:20px; height:10px; margin:auto; text-align:center; background:#fff; padding:10px; color:#000; }
</style>

<div class="ioitem ioitem1">
    <div class="number">1</div>
    <div class="width">1</div>
    <div class="base">1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple approaches that would work here - the first one doesn't require you to change your HTML at all, and is to set the number you want at the top to position: absolute, then transform it to where you want it to go.

```
  <style>
    .numberContainer {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .numberContainer div{
      width: 30px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .numberContainer .number{
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(calc(-50% - 0.1em), -50%);
    }
  </style>
  <div class="ioitem ioitem1">
      <div class="numberContainer">
          <div class="number">1</div>
          <div class="width">3</div>
          <div class="base">D</div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Alternatively, if you don't wanna use position: absolute on your contents, you can just flip the order of the HTML to match your diagram and do it that way.

```
  <style>
    .numberContainer {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .numberContainer div{
      width: 30px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .numberContainer .number{
      transform: translate(calc(-50% - 0.1em), -50%);
    }
  </style>
  <div class="ioitem ioitem1">
      <div class="numberContainer">
          <div class="width">3</div>
          <div class="number">1</div>
          <div class="base">D</div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Hopefully one of these does what you need!